# Some troubles using Screen Manager without .kv file

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I'm trying to make an application with Pthon and kivy. I'm working on the Login/Register part of it. I'm trying to make a screen for each (Login and register) and connect them with the ScreenManager, but WITHOUT .kv file. If it is impossible I'd like to write the less i can in hte .kv file

I've seen some tutorials saying that i had to inherit "Screen" for each window class and create a class for the ScreenManager. Then, at the .kv file, set the 'name' variable for each class. After that, i should use 'root.app.current = ' at the 'on_click' function. I've tryed to do it just with python, and then, with a little bit of KvLang, but it hasn't worked.

I've tried to use the commented part of the code and it hasn't worked too

the .py file

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #self.transition = FadeTransition()
        #self.add_widget(RegisterWindow(name='register'))
        #self.add_widget(LoginWindow(name='login'))

    def screen_transition(self, *args):
        self.current = 'register'


class RegisterWindow(Screen, FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = 'register'
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Username', size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .7}))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False, size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .5, 'y': .7})
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Password', size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .5}))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False, password=True, size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .5, 'y': .5})
        self.add_widget(self.password)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='E-mail', size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .3}))
        self.email = TextInput(multiline=False, size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .5, 'y': .3})
        self.add_widget(self.email)
        self.btn = Button(text='Register', size_hint=(.9, .2), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'y': .03})
        self.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.btn.bind(on_press=self.submit)

    def submit(self, instance):
        username = self.username.text
        password = self.password.text
        email = self.email.text

        info = {'Username': username,
                'Password': password,
                'Email': email}

        file = open('data.csv', 'a+')
        file.write(f'{info["Username"]},{info["Password"]},{info["Email"]}\n')
        file.close()

        self.username.text = ''
        self.password.text = ''
        self.email.text = ''

        print(info)


class LoginWindow(Screen, FloatLayout):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(LoginWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.name = 'login'
            self.btn2 = Button(text='Go')
            self.add_widget(self.btn2)
            self.btn2.bind(on_press = ScreenManagement().screen_transition())


class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

the .kv file

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    RegisterWindow:
        name: 'register'
    LoginWindow:
        name: 'login'
```

It raises the exception: kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "register".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't actually need any `kv` at all. Here is a version of your code without `kv`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class RegisterWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Username', size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .7}))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False, size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .5, 'y': .7})
        self.add_widget(self.username)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Password', size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .5}))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False, password=True, size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .5, 'y': .5})
        self.add_widget(self.password)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='E-mail', size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .05, 'y': .3}))
        self.email = TextInput(multiline=False, size_hint=(.45, .1), pos_hint={'x': .5, 'y': .3})
        self.add_widget(self.email)
        self.btn = Button(text='Register', size_hint=(.9, .2), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'y': .03})
        self.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.btn.bind(on_press=self.submit)

    def submit(self, instance):
        username = self.username.text
        password = self.password.text
        email = self.email.text

        info = {'Username': username,
                'Password': password,
                'Email': email}

        file = open('data.csv', 'a+')
        file.write(f'{info["Username"]},{info["Password"]},{info["Email"]}\n')
        file.close()

        self.username.text = ''
        self.password.text = ''
        self.email.text = ''

        print(info)


class LoginWindow(Screen):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(LoginWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.btn2 = Button(text='Go')
            self.add_widget(self.btn2)
            self.btn2.bind(on_press = self.screen_transition)

        def screen_transition(self, *args):
            self.manager.current = 'register'


class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManagement(transition=FadeTransition())
        sm.add_widget(LoginWindow(name='login'))
        sm.add_widget(RegisterWindow(name='register'))
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

The main changes are the building of the `ScreenManagement` instance and the child `Screens` in the `App` `build()` method. Also, changed the binding of the `Go` `Button` to a `screen_transition()` method in the same class. And your `Screen` classes don't need to extend `FloatLayout` (`Screen` is a `RelativeLayout`).

Comment: Awesome, that was very helpful, I try to avoid the language all together and this really shed some light on issues I've been facing. Cheers.

Comment: The `kv` language is an awesome tool that can actually make app development easier and better.

Comment: I have read that various places, I think because I'm new to Python as well it was just a little too much. The issues I faced is when I was utilizing python variables to create buttons dynamically I could not get those variables into that environment nicely. I am wrapping V1 of what app now, I think I will try to go back and recreate it using the KV language as well, will more than likely be posting many questions.

Answer (score 1):

## Error - ScreenManagerException

```
   File ".../main.py", line 17, in screen_transition
     self.current = 'register'
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 544, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 1038, in on_current
     screen = self.get_screen(value)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 1064, in get_screen
     raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "register".
```

## Root Cause

The error occurred when Kivy is trying to switch to the screen name, `'register'` in the code, `self.current = 'register'` in method `screen_transition()`.

When your Kivy app runs, there are two instances of `ScreenManagement`. One of it is created via kv file, `ScreenManagement:` and the other one via Python code, `ScreenManagement().screen_transition()`. The instance created in kv file, has screen names, `'register'` and  `'login'`. Whereas the one created in Python code, does not contain screen names, `'register'`and `'login'`.

## Solution

The following enhancements are required to solve the problem.

### kv file

1. Replace root rule, `ScreenManagement:` with class rule, `<ScreenManagement>:`

#### Snippets - kv file

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

<ScreenManagement>:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    RegisterWindow:
        name: 'register'
    LoginWindow:
        name: 'login'
```

### py file

1. Implement a method `callback` to clear widgets and add widget
2. Replace `self.btn2.bind(on_press=ScreenManagement().screen_transition())` with `self.btn2.bind(on_press=self.callback)`
3. Remove all methods in class ScreenManagement with keyword, `pass`

#### Snippets - py file

```
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

...

class LoginWindow(Screen, FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        ...
        self.btn2.bind(on_press=self.callback)

    def callback(self, instance):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(ScreenManagement())
```

## Output

[image: Result]